# Android Emulator doesn't connect to Firebase emulator

Tags: android, firebase

I created a Firebase emulator and use it with the android emulator and it always worked. It gave me an error saying

> An internal error has occurred [unable to resolve host 10.0.2.2 :No address associated with host name]

I downloaded the key from GCP and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable to point to it. What could be causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to security issues on android after api 27. Try running this on a AVD with android api 27.